# How do I define color groups based on numerical threshold values for ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scatter-plot, threshold

I have a data set that contains 2 variables `x` = event number & `y` = assay amplitude. I am trying to create a scatterplot in `ggplot2` where all of the points that are `> 3000` are colored in one color and all of the points `< 3000` are in a different color.

I can get the plot and change the color for all data points, but can't figure out how to define a color scheme based on the value threshold.

Here is a sample of the data I'm using:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(399, 16022, 14756, 2609, 1131, 12135, 
                                 7097, 12438, 12604, 14912, 11042, 
                                 14024, 7033, 4971, 15533, 4507, 4627, 
                                 12600, 7458, 14557, 3999, 3154, 6073),
                  y=c(3063.40137, 3687.42041, 3911.856, 
                                    4070.91748, 4089.99561, 4095.50317,
                                    4159.899, 4173.117, 4177.78955, 
                                    4186.46875, 4201.874, 4272.022, 
                                    638.615, 649.8995, 668.8346,
                                    688.754639, 711.92, 712.689636, 
                                    721.1352, 737.841, 741.0727, 
                                    755.2549, 756.730652))
```

Comment: Give a look at `?cut` and see how that might help.

Comment: Also, are the cuts based on `x` or `y` values (or, both)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really just need to do a new indicator variable for this. As @hrbrmstr says, `cut` is a good general way to do this (works for as many cutpoints as you want).

```
dat$col <- cut(dat$y,
               breaks = c(-Inf, 3000, Inf),
               labels = c("<=3000", ">3000"))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = col)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: see `+scale_color_manual(values = c("darkolivegreen", "chartreuse"))`. See `?scale_color_manual` for details.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done on the fly with an `ifelse` statement and without having to create an extra column in the dataset:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(y>3000, 'red', 'blue'))) +
scale_colour_manual(labels = c("<3000", ">3000"), values=c('blue', 'red')) + 
labs(color = "Values")
```

Comment: What if i wanted to use `ifelse`to get three colors for, say, y>3000, y > 2000 and y < 2000?